# How to get value from previous calculated column in Pyspark / Python data set

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a new column(B) in a Pyspark / Python table.
New column(B) is sum of : current value of column(A) + previous value of column(B)

[desired output example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPisL.png)

```
`Id   a     b
1    977   977
2    3665  4642
3    1746  6388
4    2843  9231
5    200   9431`
```

current Col B = current Col A + previous Col B ;
example Row 4 : 9231 (col B) = 2843 (col A) + 6388 (previous Col B value)

(for 1st row since there is no previous value for B so it is 0)

Please help me with the Python / PySpark query code

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Without the context I may be wrong, but it seems your trying to do a cumulative sum of column A :

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

df = df.withColumn('B', sf.sum(df.A).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(
Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
```

EDIT:

If you need to iteratively add new rows based on the last value of B and assuming the value of B in the dataframe doesn't change in the meantime, I think you'd better memorize B in a standard python variable and build the following row with that.

```py
previous_B = 0
# your code to get new A
previous_B += new_A
new_row = spark.createDataFrame([(new_A, previous_B)])
df = df.union(new_row)
```

Comment: Actually Column A always has a new value, Column B is sum of Column A value + old Column B value

Comment: OK, so you build your table line by line, and wants to update column B before having all the lines of column A.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build table line by line where I already have value for A but I am creating value of  B by calling the last value for B

Comment: So basically each time you need to select the last line of your dataframe and then select the column B in that line. You can do that with spark querry but as far as I know it would probably be pretty complicated for what you want to do. 
Spark dataframes work like databases and aren't made for accessing some specific rows or elements like normal arrays. So I think it's better to simply memorise the last B value somewhere else.

I've edited my answer with another solution.